# Dice roll question

Tags: probability, simulation, dice

Suppose you roll a fair die two times. Let  A  be the event "the sum of the throws equals 5" and  B  be the event "at least one of the throws is a  4 ". Calculate p(A|B)?
How to compute this question by simulation

Comment: There is not actually a question.  Actually writing a simulation to roll two dice and count the number of events A and B should not be difficult in your favourite programming language

Answer (score 1):

One possibility out of many.  Using R to do a million 2-roll experiments
for about 2 or 3 significant digits of accuracy:

These happen to be trivial combinatorial
problems, so we know the exact answers. In more intricate probability
simulations some of several answers may not be known, but it is a good
idea to look for a probability or expectation in the model that **is** known, and simulate that also, as a check on the validity of the simulation. (Even before you start writing computer code, you can consider whether there is a relatively obvious answer you can include in the simulation.)

It is good practice to say what software you used (R i386 3.4.4) and to show the seed you used for your simulation
so that someone can replicate your work if they wish.

```
set.seed(2021)
d1 = sample(1:6, 10^6, rep=T)
d2 = sample(1:6, 10^6, rep=T)

mean(d1+d2==5)
[1] 0.111241      # aprx 4/36 = 1/9
2*sd(d1+d2==5)/1000
[1] 0.000628861   # aprx 95% margin of sim error
4/36
[1] 0.1111111     # 1/9
```

*Notes:* Four possibilities `(1,4), (2,3), (3,2), (4,1)` out of 36.
Numeric vectors `d1` and `d2` are of length one million.
Logical vector `d1 + d2 == 5` has elements `TRUE` and `FALSE`;
its `mean` is the proportion of its `TRUE`s.
The margin of error uses a 95% Wald CI. When possible it is
desirable to program a margin of error. Here the CI is $0.11124 \pm 0.0001.$

```
mean(d1==4 | d2==4)
[1] 0.305282      # aprx 11/36
2*sd(d1==4 | d2==4)/1000
[1] 0.000921054   # aprx 95% margin of sim error
1 - (5/6)^2
[1] 0.3055556     # 1 - P(No 4's)
11/36
[1] 0.3055556
```

One more check: We know that the mean of the sum of two fair
dice is $7,$ so you could look at that for verification. if other
results were not known.

```
mean(d1 + d2)
[1] 6.999453
```

*Addendum:* Another approach in R:

```
set.seed(1234)
die = 1:6
nr.4 = replicate(10^6, sum(sample(die,2,rep=T)==4))
mean(nr.4 > 0)
[1] 0.305098
table(nr.4)/10^6
nr.4
       0        1        2 
0.694902 0.277345 0.027753 

tot = replicate(10^6, sum(sample(die,2,rep=T)))
mean(tot==5)
[1] 0.110645
table(tot)/10^6
tot
       2        3        4        5        6        7 
0.027817 0.055704 0.083312 0.110645 0.139074 0.166842 
       8        9       10       11       12 
0.139007 0.111190 0.083041 0.055497 0.027871
```

Comment: Thanks so much......